# Eliminating the visual "contact bounce" of accept/unaccept/accept in the reputation history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)

The latest reputation history tracking sometimes shows a sequence of accept-unaccept-accept as +30/-15, +60/-15, or whatever. When expanded, you see the three events happening during the same minute, so the data makes perfect sense.

[image: An example of reputation stats with "contact bounce"]

However, the unaccept information is somewhat misleading: most likely, the users simply double-clicked the "check" mark, realized that only a single click is required, and promptly corrected themselves. It would be nice if the site waited for a few seconds before recording an accept or an unaccept, in the same way the hardware waits for a contact to stop bouncing before deciding that a key has indeed been pressed or released.

**EDIT** It looks like upvoting suffers from the same issue.

Comment: There have been a lot of bug reports/feature requests about this particular aspect of the new rep system. I suppose it's time for someone to look into changing it. By design or not, it might not be the best design, as it's confuzzling a lot of folks.

Comment: +1, I have a single answer today that was accepted / unaccepted a total of 9 times in 4 minutes.  Something seems amiss.

Comment: Some rollup or hiding *will* be done for this vote repeat/reversal case, we're just working on some more important bits behind the scenes for the moment.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm now seeing this for up / down votes as well.  Just got 3 up + 3 down votes on the same answer in a 1 minute period.  That seems really amiss.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9548887/23283

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the "double click" issue *really* is the case, perhaps a *better* fix would be to prevent a user double clicking it in the first place. Since unaccepts happen a lot less often, maybe there should be a confirmation box "Do you really want to unaccept this answer?" when the user attempts to unaccept it. Then there won't be all these excess events to deal with.

Comment: I don't think a confirmation box is the answer to the simple UI problem displayed here. There's an excessive amount of friction involved in a confirmation dialog, and it would have to be displayed each time. It's much easier to just write code that deals with the excess events. There *will* be times that people unaccept and then reaccept, even if they have to confirm the dialog to do so. What will you do then?