# The new rep handling needs some noise-cancelling hysteresis

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, information-display

The [new handling of rep calculations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319) is great, but [as bitmask predicted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124014/134069) the fact that each change shows up makes the rep display a bit confusing and rather "noisy."

Apparently, users constantly accept, then unaccept, then accept answers — usually doing all three within seconds of each other. Similarly people upvote, then un-upvote, then re-upvote again, within seconds. See the image below.

As engineers, we know that the usual response to this kind of noise is to throw a bit of [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) into the system, as when debouncing the input from a keystroke or mouse click.

I suggest that events on the same object (question or answer) within, say, a minute of each other that cancel each other out should be filtered out of the display. So referring to the image below, rather than

```
+30 41 mins ago  accept    Select all input tag in without certain attribute in Jquery
-15 41 mins ago  unaccept  Select all input tag in without certain attribute in Jquery
```

...we'd just see

```
+15 41 mins ago  accept    Select all input tag in without certain attribute in Jquery
```

...as we used to.

[image]