# Empty sections on the Reputation Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

I guess as a side effect of [the fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125137/163863) for [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again), we now get empty sections on the reputation page;

[image]

Comment: Yes, there's no sane way to avoid this, not without dramatically increasing database load for a very rare case.

Comment: @NickCraver - Sure there is, a one-liner of javascript to hide the row of the content of the score line is `0` (or if there are no children, or whatever). Not everything needs to be fixed on the backend.

Comment: @eykanal - A 0 may be +15 and -15, both valid changes which isn't fetched or known to the page at this time...fetching that is the "dramatically increasing database load" I mentioned above.   It's not as simple as you suppose...trust me.

Comment: @NickCraver Would it be feasible for the details partial view to render a message explaining there's nothing to show? Something like "No actions resulted in an appreciable change" (but less awkwardly worded) in the case where it didn't actually generate any rows. I get why you can't know in advance, but I think the empty space comes off as a bit weird to people.

Comment: @NickCraver - So, I see that the `loaded-body` row isn't populated until the triangle is clicked. However, when clicked, it's easy to tell whether it's empty or not... it's a check whether the child table `tbl-reputation` has any rows. I guess you could, on page load, automatically populate the table for rows with "total rep = 0", detect empty ones, and not show them, but at the cost (as you said) of a few more database hits per pageload, which is a non-trivial tradeoff.

Comment: @NickCraver - by the way, I don't think this is as rare as you think... I have two 0-rep rows on my screen, and it seems that the two other folks here also see a few on their rep page.

Comment: @TimStone: "Your reputation changed, but it has no effect" "Your reputation was eaten by a Grue" "Nothing to look at here" "0-Damage dealt to your reputation" "Reputation changes were reflected by the magic shield" "Hi, I slipped and accidentally deleted some records from the database, but everything should be fine now, you won't miss this reputation"

Comment: @Tim - aye, that we can do, I'll take a peek here in a bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the next build, you'll get a message instead of that blank area upon expanding: "There were no net reputation changes on this day"