# Why is a day with zero reputation change displayed?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty sections on the Reputation Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page)

If you get neither upvotes nor downvotes at a day, the day will not be displayed in the reputation tab. So this makes me wonder what happened on 22nd May:

[image: reputationttab]

Edit: Other days where I was active (commenting, voting) with zero rep change are not showing up at all. So why is May 22 displayed, while May 17,18,19 are not?

Comment: I know I was active on the site during the day :-) As on May 17,18,19th which don't have had any rep changes. But the latter three are not displayed as having zero rep change, they are simply left out.

Comment: You had some reputation changes that were undone shortly thereafter, like an answer that was accepted and then unaccepted (resulting in no net change).

Comment: Ok, I think that nails it

Comment: Related: [Empty sections on the Reputation Page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125151)