# No reputation changes on this day means

Tags: support, reputation

In my reputation tab of my profile page there are a lot of dates with zero reputation changes.
But, some of them showing the message,

[image]

We are not showing reputation changes for all dates. If the system shows there is zero rep change means there should be something happened like below,

[image]

I need to clarify or get a support from the community that why most of the users got this message several times.

I think this post is not the dup of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page), which had a feature request to show any reason for zero rep change. I need the reason for showing `There were no net reputation changes on this day.`

Comment: The question you linked mentions [the reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again/125137#125137) for this.

Comment: @Bart, yes it's a dup, see this another [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133599/why-is-a-day-with-zero-reputation-change-displayed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That usually seems to appear when a vote happened, but was undone again within a grace period. Then in the end no votes are registered, but instead that message appears.