# 0 reputation in list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty sections on the Reputation Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page)

I was creeping on a user's reputation tab on their profile, when I ran into a peculiarity that caught my eye:

[image: There's a Zero Rep Day!]

Normally, dates with no change are omitted, appropriately, but in this case, July 19 is listed, even though there was no reputation gained or lost on that day. Why is July 19 listed, while July 18 is not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *were* reputation changes that day, but the posts causing the changes have since been removed.

When viewing your own history, you can check the box "Show removed posts". However, that is not available when viewing other users' histories.

**Edit:** Additionally, since you can't see other users' votes, it's possible you're seeing this because the user's only reputation change was from downvoting answers.

Comment: It could also be that the user only received reputation changes for down-votes they made on other users' answers... the reputation change we would see would still show 0.

Comment: Right. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: This doesn't happen because of removed posts anymore, or downvotes, it only happens in the vote/unvote case, for example an answer was accepted then unaccepted netting a 0 for the day.

Comment: @Nick wouldn't it make sense to either turn off the day header or show the +/- activities? It seems there are two checks happening independently that could probably be coordinated. Not a serious issue of course, just fit and finish stuff.