# "No reputation changes on this day"... OK, why did you tell me this?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [0 reputation in list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142190/0-reputation-in-list)

My [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370483/quantumsoup?tab=reputation) says

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

What's the point of telling me this? Days when there are no reputation changes are normally not included, so this is either a bug or at least inconsistent behavior:

[image]

There're several similar questions all tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) so I'm going to assume this is a new bug.

Comment: AFAIK this appears when there were reputation events on that day, but they were cancelled. For example, if you upvote a post and then undo your upvote. It will not appear on days that no reputation events occur.

Comment: @WesleyMurch In days when there are no reputation changes the date itself isn't shown. It's either a bug or terribly inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> There were no ***net*** reputation changes on this day

There was a downvote that was then reversed, there was a change you may have momentarily noticed (why we show the message at all, it's also technically very hard to remove) but no ***net*** changes on that day.

Comment: I kinda wish there was a way to show all the events (uncollapsed) like when you first pushed out the new rep-system. Of course, it should default to "off" since it'll be full of noise.

Comment: @Mysticial - It's definitely possible, maybe a clickable link on the end of that message?

Comment: Yeah, or a checkbox at the bottom of the rep page that will show *all* events. (similar to the one that shows deleted posts)

Comment: That's not technically correct, because there are possible situations where you have 0 net change but they show (you downvote 5 answers and get 1 up vote for -5*2 +10 = 0) and these will show the changes. it's not about a lack of net change, but about deleted changes.

Answer (score 7):

The reputation history knows that you had one or more reputation events on the given day, whatever they may be. When you request the details, the individual reputation events are grouped so that self-cancelling events are [rolled up and removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again/125137#125137).

If this roll-up results in nothing to display, you're told that

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

Previously, it [simply displayed an empty set of details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page), which was confusing. Ideally, you wouldn't see the collapsed (or pre-expanded, as the case may be) entry to begin with, but it's cost prohibitive to know to do this for the high level view, especially for a case that's relatively rare.