# Why my flag get result as none?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I flagged my [own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182151/no-reputation-changes-on-this-day-means) post as exact duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142190/0-reputation-in-list) post.

It got a result of *none*.

> [image]

Then, I thought that it was not a dupe that it might had some unique details. But, today morning I saw that the post was closed as duplicate as I flagged.

What actually happened? I need clarifications on that. If it's a duplicate question means my flag should be accepted as helpful. but, it returns the result *none*. What does it mean? Then after long time(about 4 to 5 hours), the post was closed as duplicate. I got confused.

Comment: No free hand circle? :(

Comment: Why did you flag it anyway since you voted to close it already?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, I don't know this rule about not to flag after casting a close vote, I thought both are same

Comment: No they're not. In case you were wondering, if you had tried to flag it as "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate", you would have noticed that it either converted that to a close vote, or the system would have rejected it saying you've already voted. That's because you can already vote to close your own questions so you should be using close votes, not flags, where you can. And even if they *were* the same, I still don't see why you needed to flag your question again, let alone do so with a custom flag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, Ok, I flag and and cast a close vote for same thing, but the result is none- why?

Comment: As a 3K+ user, when I click on flag on any question and click on *it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate* then the popup is redirected to close vote popup (So it doesn't considered as a flag). I think the same thing should be done when we are flagging own question with [250+ reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, my helpful flag count is not get incremented and that flag is not get counted on declined or disputed too

Comment: @hims056: You mean the system doesn't already do that? If that's really the case (we need someone who can verify this), it should be reported separately as a bug.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I think it doesn't do that for 250-3000 rep users. If it is already there then the flag would have not been added to his flag history. And yeah once it is confirmed, it will be reported as a bug. (by anyone)

Comment: Flags get dismissed as "none" when your own actions would have validated your flag automatically in order to stop people gaming their flag weights.

Comment: @Flexo, so you are saying that the community has a system to prevent that the OP to flag the post when he/she confirmed that it would get closed