# pre-mature Notification for Comment Everywhere privilege

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm not sure why, but I received a Notification stating: `Congrats, you've gained the privilege – comment everywhere learn more`.

However, I currently only have reputation of 40, while a [reputation of 50 is required for this privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Feels like a potential minor bug.  (thanks regardless for an excellent site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reputation history is an entry for today saying

> There were no net reputation changes on this day

That is an indication for a reputation change that was removed later on. If you wouldn't gotten any reputation today then there would not even be a "today" notice.

So you had 50 reputation or more but later that reputation was removed. For example a user accepted your answer and removed the accept mark later.

In the meantime you got the notification.

But since you don't have the reputation anymore you will not have that privilege anyway.

Comment: Thx for the feedback; however, reviewing my [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1742657/donfede?tab=reputation) I only positive marks, without any record of negative marks (unlike here on meta ;)).

Comment: See [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page)

Comment: makes sense now.