# Reputation decreased with no reason

Tags: support, reputation

I had reputation of 2244 around yesterday. Now, it's automatically decreased by around 20 - 24 and it is 2220.

I have gone through the Reputation tab and also [audit reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation). I haven't found any significant reason of this decrease.

**Refer below Image:**
[image: Reputation Error]

Could anyone advice me on how to check this?

Comment: [Auditing Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/260388) may be useful

Comment: I have done this as well. In that also, there is no reason of it

Comment: Some post might have got deleted. That could be the reason. Ping some user with moderation tools. They will help.

Comment: @Sinister in that case entry would show in the reputation tab.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd One of the questions to which I answered was deleted by a moderator some weeks ago. It didn't show in my reputation tab and also in the audit. If the post is deleted by the moderator, it will be shown in moderation tools. OP might check deleted recent answers in his activity tab..

Comment: @Sinister how to ping moderators?

Comment: They will be in chat rooms. If there is a main room for Stack Overflow, then ping them with  @ before their names. Someone will help.

Comment: @Sinister: Did you have "show deleted posts" checked? I really don't think any posts will be hidden just because they were deleted by diamond mods.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah. I checked. I knew which post was deleted  by a diamond mod by checking there. Now, I can't check it because the post is no more recent. It's an old post.

Comment: @Sinister Please advice to me from where I can able to see those deleted posts?

Comment: you should delete it from here and raise on MSO. the mods can help you there.

Comment: There obviously have been reputation events but those where cancelled out. Think as: An upvote that has been undone, an accept that was unaccepted, on the same post. See [this comment from Nick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125151/empty-sections-on-the-reputation-page#comment352600_125151).

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu a question you had a +3/-3 answer on was roomba'd. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798514/stringbuilder-appends-boolean-values-differently/45798549#45798549