# "unupvote" shown in mobile version of rep page but not on desktop version

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

I was pleased to note that [events such as *unupvotes* are not shown in the rep graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes/123330#123330). On exploring further, I noticed that it only shows up when I view it on my phone and not on my desktop. Am I missing something?

Example - note [upvote-unupvote-upvote on 23rd March](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115845/shawn-chin?tab=reputation).

**Viewing from my iPhone:**

[image: unuvotes shown in mobile version]

**Viewing on Firefox 10.0.2 (Ubuntu):**

[image: no teh unupvotez]

p.s. On a side note, are votes/unuvotes rate-limited or subject to a grace period? Or can a milicious user flood someone's rep page by repeated toggling? I lack the nads to try it out myself.

---

#### Update:

As [@Mystical pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127357/unupvote-shown-in-mobile-version-of-rep-page-but-not-on-desktop-version/127363#127363), [consequtive toggling of votes are hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again/125137#125137) to avoid unnecessary verbosity and trolling activities. So this question boils down to **why is the mobile version not doint the same?** Is it a bug, or by design?

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [New reputation is too verbose: upvote/unupvote, upvote again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124738/169611)

Originally, the main site had the same "problem". That is: users double-clicking on the arrows causing the votes to "bounce". That was changed so that these vote reversals are merged on no longer show up in the rep page.

But I guess the mobile site hasn't gotten as much attention from the devs?