# Stackoverflow possible reputation bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I am not 100% too sure whether to class this as a bug or not.

I just noticed that I currently have 1,104 reputation on SO.

my Reputation increased after refreshing to 1,119, after examining my reputation history:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765866/daryl-gill?tab=reputation

It does not list what caused the increase on my reputation.

then after looking at my reputation again it has decreased to 1,104

Could this be a bug? or a glitch within the system? or should be ignored?

Comment: Someone accepted an answer of yours and unaccepted.

Comment: If this is the case, then shouldn't it be listed on the reputation list? stating why the increase/decrease?

Comment: @DannyBeckett refreshed to 1,119 then refreshed again to see 1,104

Comment: @DarylGill: Accepts and unaccepts that occur on the same day get collapsed and hidden from view.

Comment: This is ticked..

Comment: @Mysticial is correct (as usual). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15560857/timeline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you described can be explained in one of a few ways:

1. Three people upvoted your questions simultaneously, then removed their upvotes
2. One person upvoted an answer, another upvoted a question, and both votes were redacted
3. One person accepted your answer, then unaccepted it.
4. A question of yours was deleted with 3 upvotes

The most logical explanation here is #3, as it's the simplest. Votes which are added and removed on the same day are not shown in the reputation page, as they could have been simple mistakes that were corrected moments later.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it, as 15 reputation isn't that much to be squabbling over, especially since you didn't loose any privileges over it.

Comment: That is very true, just thought to bring this up incase this might not be intented

Comment: Well, it was actually made that way to [prevent history spamming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again). Very annoying.

Comment: @DarylGill chances are that if there's a reputation fluctuation it isn't a bug. It's either the result of a deleted question/answer, and you can always check through the [`/reputation`](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page, and it will give you a very detailed explanation.