# How can your reputation points amount decrease without downvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Today I've seen my reputation points reach 2162 points. After some time I've opened one of new SO  questions and see reputation 2147. I still have 2 tabs opened in my FF showing 2 different reputations but when I go to my reputation summary I do not see any downvotes (last time my point count was decreased was 2 points yesterday) so - where did my points go?

Comment: It's possible that an answer of yours was unaccepted, or an answer with positive upvotes was deleted.  In the case of the latter, you can go to the Reputation tab, and check the "Show removed posts" to see if that's the issue.

Comment: Your reputation went down by 15, so someone might have unaccepted one of your answers in favor of another answer.

Comment: @Bill but this should appear in the reputation tab, no?

Comment: Questions that you have answered may have been deleted. That should show up in your reputation summary though. If it doesn't, maybe it's due to caching?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not sure. I know that +15 shows up in your reputation history for an accept, but I don't think -15 does for an unaccept. I think the +15 just disappears.

Comment: Can you see deleted questions/answers when you have 2k rep? If an accepted answer was deleted, or the question was deleted, or the user was deleted, the rep would drop (I think). I'm pretty sure I've seen that happen and saw the reason, and I see -15 for unaccepted answers (on 2013-06-23 on SO, for instance), but maybe there's a rep limit that can hide it?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @AlexPoole. I can see the -15 on your rep history, but not on Artur's.

Comment: @Bill See [my other comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206969/how-can-your-reputation-points-amount-decrease-without-downvotes#comment657891_206971).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mystery solved, [Bill was right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206969/how-can-your-reputation-points-amount-decrease-without-downvotes/206972#comment657877_206969).

[This answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19903611/447356) was accepted for 12 seconds as you can see in the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19727557/timeline):

> [image]

During those 12 seconds of fame, the live update identified the +15 and increased the reputation. By design, live update will never reduce the reputation so when it got unaccepted, only page refresh showed it.

The final piece of the puzzle is: why doesn't it appear in the reputation history? And the answer is because the accept and unaccept events happened in the "context of a day", as Nick says [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125137/152859).

Comment: I'll ask stupid question - where do I see that - what tab in my account?

Comment: @Artur the timeline is hidden gem of Stack Exchange, just replace the URL with `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/[id here]/timeline` e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19727557/timeline`

Comment: that can be useful - thanks

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that view either. There's a mod-only timeline view that doesn't have that information.

Comment: @Bill actually my initial assumption of 24 hours was wrong, see my edit. :)

Answer (score 6):

I have seen that reputation change when someone accepts my answer and within next few minutes *(not really sure about the exact time, but it is usually less than 5 minutes)* unaccepted my answer, then on already open page reputation will stay as +15, and one new windows it will be the real (-15).

This activity never appears in reputation history, I have seen changes in reputation history if some old answer is unaccepted.

Comment: Explanations: 1) if an accept and unaccept (or any event and reversal) occur on the sane UTC day, they are rolled up together and not displayed in the history; 2) only positive reputation changes are live refreshed. Negative and reversal changes are only updated on a page refresh.

Comment: @animuson Note that the order is important there.  An un-accept and then re-accept in the same day *is* shown.