# Lose an achievement event

Tags: support, achievements-dialog

It seems that Stackoverflow has lost one of my achievement event, as I'm not sure, I just describe what I saw.

1. I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612022/understanding-hash-implementation-and-its-memory-in-redis/37700039#37700039) today
2. I received a "vote up"
3. I received the "accept" achievement event and get my new reputation
4. I saw the "accept" flag on the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612022/understanding-hash-implementation-and-its-memory-in-redis/37700039#37700039)
5. I fresh the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612022/understanding-hash-implementation-and-its-memory-in-redis/37700039#37700039) minutes later, the "accept" flag gone and my reputation reduced to former value
6. I checked the "achievement" events, the one I received at step 3 is gone, the one I received at step 2 remains

There is another explanation besides Stackoverflow got bug: The author withdrawn the accept operation; the effect of withdraw event is not add another event but delete the related "accept" event. I never withdrawn the accept operation so I am not sure about that explanation.

Actually, I'm a little curious about the process of the 'accept' operation. I think it's more like, instead of change the reputations instantly, the operation just write an event to a distributed queue, then a realtime job consume the event from the queue, finish the actions including add the reputation of author and answerer, push a notification to author and answerer, etc.

Comment: You've got two questions here, but: it is most likely that the OP withdrew his acceptance. The rep changes are more-or-less instantaneous. I don't think I ever see a specific "answer accepted event", but I could be misremembering, or it might not be available or prominent in the iOS app. I certainly don't remember ever being *explicitly* told that an acceptance has been withdrawn, though that's happened to me; all I see is the -15.

Comment: @DanBron yes, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event wasn't lost, it was hidden. If a vote occurs and then the retraction of that same event also occurs on the *same day*, then the event is just hidden from the history like nothing ever happened, rather than displaying an event and then the undoing of that event next to each other.

So your answer was accepted, and then the user unaccepted the answer shortly after. If they had unaccepted the next day, you'd see the accept event for the original day, and an unaccept event on the following day when it occurred. But since both occurred the same day, neither of those is shown.

This was done to prevent users [spamming other users' reputation histories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again) with consistent event/unevent strings that had no effect on their reputation.